# How can I reorder/simplify HTML code to display on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a web page with a two-column layout for desktop screens and the HTML is written in a particular order to achieve the desired layout, basic set up below:

```
<div>
    <div class="left-column">
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Text here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- columns to sit side by side -->
```

However, for smaller screens, this layout has to be simplified (one column, top > down) but I'm finding it difficult to re-position these elements with media queries because of the original ordering of the HTML. For smaller screens, I'd like the layout to be as follows:

```
<div>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <img>
    <p>Text here...</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, I want only one div and the `<img>` to move inbetween the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements.

**How can I achieve this alternate HTML layout which will display only on smaller screens?**

Comment: Does it work? yes. Is it accepted? No. This will slow down the website alot since you basicly make 2 webpages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @koningdavid. My plan was to do this only for certain sections of the page (i.e. ones with complex layouts) - still bad practice?

Comment: What is also bad practice, is to put the content in the HTML in the wrong order as you do in the desktop example. This will lead to screen readers and search engine to read/interpret the text in the wrong order.

Comment: @RoToRa Valid point there... but sometimes you need to separate elements for design/layout purposes or visual effect - would you advise against this?

Comment: @RoToRa It depends on what exactly the visual effect is. My guess is you want a table-like design with the two headers being the same height. In that case you could use a small bit of presentional JavaScript to equalize the heights of the elements.

Comment: @RoToRa see above for the desired layout - my question has been edited

Comment: What exactly is your difficulty? You don't even need media queries for that. Just have the two columns float. When they fit side by side, they will, when not, they wont - automatically. Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/vBdyN/ (Resize window to test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crude solution but this one's a no-script one.

Keep a duplicate `img` element in the left div as well between the `h1` & `p`. Keep it `dislay:none` by default. Then using media queries make it visible when you wish to show a single column view & hide the other `img` element or `right-column` div altogether.

Comment: Do you know if pages would be penalized (by search engines) if duplicate images/content is used?

Comment: The last I checked the search engine will raise a flag for using `display:none`. But, then you can apply the styling from an external css instead of writing it in-line. In which case, the search engine will still raise a flag for duplicate content. To counter that, keep the value of the `img:alt` attribute different for both the tags. That's the only easy way out I can think of.
Otherwise, you'll have to manage the layout using some tedious css & script combination or deliver custom markup from the server depending upon user's display.

Answer (score 1):

if you are familiar with PHP you should use a library (like http://mobiledetect.net/) to detect the device your site is run from and then serve the version you want to display.

In your case you would have an if/else sentence with your divs wrapped in a PHP variable depending on the results of mobiledetect. This makes sure you don't have duplicated content (which is bad for SEO).

Answer (score 0):

On looking at your HTML it seems like both desktop and mobile devices are about to show the same content with only difference in class name give to div.

If you are doing like that my suggestion is: Keep same name for div, do not repeat it. Like you hide the div, write separate styles for different screens (Media Queries). Try to write styles in percentage, so that only few elements require separate styles in mobile devices.

```
eg: 
/* Desktop styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    /* Styles for elements upto 600  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think to build a responsive design (if possible) if targeting it for desktop and mobile, because that really saves a lot of time and gives a graceful solution.
However, as per your question, it is not a bad practice at all and is accepted if you have different sets of content for them. A lot of big product companies have used this approach.

Please check this link, might help - http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/19/do-mobile-desktop-interfaces-belong-together/

Comment: the thing is: the actual content is exactly the same, it's just the HTML that is reordered to get elements displaying one after another (top > down).